# Create a new field manually from given function. Userforms plugin

Tags: php, silverstripe

I want to add some fields by default using Userforms plugin in Silverstripe 3.2
I think i found the function which adds fields when the 'Add Field' button is pressed in Gridfield, but i`m not sure and i don't know how to adda formfield type (Date input) by calling a simple function.
Here is the full function:

```
public function getFieldEditorGrid() {
    Requirements::javascript(USERFORMS_DIR . '/javascript/FieldEditor.js');

    $fields = $this->owner->Fields();

    $this->createInitialFormStep(true);
    $editableColumns = new GridFieldEditableColumns();
    $fieldClasses = singleton('EditableFormField')->getEditableFieldClasses();
    $editableColumns->setDisplayFields(array(
        'ClassName' => function($record, $column, $grid) use ($fieldClasses) {
            if($record instanceof EditableFormField) {
                return $record->getInlineClassnameField($column, $fieldClasses);
            }
        },
        'Title' => function($record, $column, $grid) {
            if($record instanceof EditableFormField) {
                return $record->getInlineTitleField($column);
            }
        }
    ));

    $config = GridFieldConfig::create()
        ->addComponents(
            $editableColumns,
            new GridFieldButtonRow(),
            GridFieldAddClassesButton::create('EditableTextField')
                ->setButtonName(_t('UserFormFieldEditorExtension.ADD_FIELD', 'Add Field'))
                ->setButtonClass('ss-ui-action-constructive'),
            GridFieldAddClassesButton::create('EditableFormStep')
                ->setButtonName(_t('UserFormFieldEditorExtension.ADD_PAGE_BREAK', 'Add Page Break')),
            GridFieldAddClassesButton::create(array('EditableFieldGroup', 'EditableFieldGroupEnd'))
                ->setButtonName(_t('UserFormFieldEditorExtension.ADD_FIELD_GROUP', 'Add Field Group')),
            new GridFieldEditButton(),
            new GridFieldDeleteAction(),
            new GridFieldToolbarHeader(),
            new GridFieldOrderableRows('Sort'),
            new GridFieldDetailForm()
        );

    $fieldEditor = GridField::create(
        'Fields',
        _t('UserDefinedForm.FIELDS', 'Fields'),
        $fields,
        $config
    )->addExtraClass('uf-field-editor');

    return $fieldEditor;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a default form field any time a user form page is created?

Comment: yes. i created a new page type, and every time a new page of that page type is created, to be automaticaly be added 2 fields. So i am thinking to call a function (when the page is created) which adds those fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can call `onAfterWrite` to set default fields after the page is saved for the first time.

```
class CustomFormPage extends UserDefinedForm {

    public function onAfterWrite() {

        if (!$this->Fields() || !$this->Fields()->exists()) {

            $nameField = new EditableTextField();
            $nameField->Name = 'Name';
            $nameField->Title = 'Name';
            $nameField->ParentID = $this->ID;
            $nameField->Required = true;
            $nameField->CustomErrorMessage = 'Please enter your name.';
            $nameField->write();

            $dateField = new EditableDateField();
            $dateField->Name = 'Date';
            $dateField->Title = 'Date';
            $dateField->ParentID = $this->ID;
            $dateField->Required = true;
            $dateField->CustomErrorMessage = 'Please enter this date.';
            $dateField->write();
        }
        parent::onAfterWrite();
    }

}
```

Comment: exactly what i need. It`s working. Thanks for help. Cheers